# Hide specific div with specific text on specific page using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hide

I would like to hide an element on a specific page by using Javascript, Jquery, or CSS. I have really limited options on how to do it because I'm using a very strict eshop solution. I can add Jquery or Javascript but it will be inserted into every single page on my eshop. I don't want to overload my website so the first condition has to be something like "if body class is .view-commodity-detail" (which is a page for every product detail) do something.

The second condition I need is to hide div with class **.detaillist-row** but only that one where the text **Luggage Volume** is located. (I need to hide .detaillist-row-value of this div parameter also - such as 50-59L, 60-69L etc..)

My code on eshop product page looks like this

```html
<body class=".view-commodity-detail">
  <div class="vc-commoditydetail_parameters">
     <div class="detaillist-row">
        <div class="detaillist-row-name">Luggage Volume</div>
        <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>50-59l</span></div>
        <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>60-69l</span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="detaillist-row">
        <div class="detaillist-row-name">Weight</div>
        <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>2500 G</span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="detaillist-row">
        <div class="detaillist-row-name">Size</div>
        <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>56 x 34 x 36 CM</span></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I was thinking about using something like this, but it would hide all my detaillist-row and I want to hide only that one where the Luggage Volume is.

```html
if ($("body").hasClass(".view-commodity-detail")) {
  if ($('.detaillist-row > .detaillist-row-name:contains("Luggage volume")').length > 0) {
     $(".detaillist-row").hide();
  }
}
```

I hope it makes any sense.

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: $('.detaillist-row:contains("Luggage Volume")').hide();

Comment: Thanks John, it works! But how do I play this code only if the certain page is with body class .view-commodity-detail?  The if ($("body").hasClass(".view-commodity-detail")) {
$('.detaillist-row:contains("objem zavazadla")').hide(); 
} doesnt work. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just put that “condition” into the selector to begin with …? `$('body.view-commodity-detail .detaillist-row:contains("Luggage Volume")').hide();`

Comment: _“but it would hide all my detaillist-row”_ - of course it did, because the element selection you ran `.hide()` on, was a completely different one than what you actually checked via your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `data-value` but you need to add `data-value` to that element which you want to hide.

like this:

```
<div class="detaillist-row-name" data-value="Luggage Volume">Luggage Volume</div>
```

```css
div[data-value="Luggage Volume"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class=".view-commodity-detail">
  <div class="vc-commoditydetail_parameters">
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name" data-value="Luggage Volume">Luggage Volume</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>50-59l</span></div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>60-69l</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name">Weight</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>2500 G</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name">Size</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>56 x 34 x 36 CM</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

or you can use `javascript`

```html
<body class=".view-commodity-detail">
  <div class="vc-commoditydetail_parameters">
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name" id="detaillist-row-name">Luggage Volume</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>50-59l</span></div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>60-69l</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name">Weight</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>2500 G</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="detaillist-row">
      <div class="detaillist-row-name">Size</div>
      <div class="detaillist-row-value"><span>56 x 34 x 36 CM</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



<script>
  var str = document.getElementById("detaillist-row-name").innerHTML;
  var n = str.replace("Luggage Volume", "");
  document.getElementById("detaillist-row-name").innerHTML = n;
</script>
```